# Get the Defect Type with the maximum Total Defect Qty

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, aggregate-functions, greatest-n-per-group

I have the following query which gets the sum of defect quantity per Defect Type :

```
SELECT 
[Defect Type]
,YEAR([Date]) AS YearOfDefect
,SUM([Total Defect Qty]) AS [Sum] FROM SupplierQuality
GROUP BY [Defect Type],YEAR([Date])
```

This is the result :

[image]

I want to have the defect type with the maximum sum of total defect quantity like below :

```
DefectType  YearOfDefect Sum    
No Impact   2019         586780230
No Impact   2018         437989564
```

Comment: I *assume* that you are after the maximum `SUM` by year? If not, what defines the 2 rows you do have, as they have the same defect type.

Comment: Say there are more Rejected than others in 2018, do you want to return Rejected for that year?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple option uses `with ties`:

```
SELECT TOP (1) WITH TIES
    [Defect Type],
    YEAR([Date]) AS YearOfDefect,
    SUM([Total Defect Qty]) AS [Sum] 
FROM SupplierQuality
GROUP BY [Defect Type], YEAR([Date])
ORDER BY RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY YEAR([Date]) ORDER BY SUM([Total Defect Qty]) DESC)
```

The downside is that this does not let you control the ordering of the resultset. If you really need that feature, then use a subquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT
        [Defect Type],
        YEAR([Date]) AS YearOfDefect,
        SUM([Total Defect Qty]) AS [Sum],
         RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY YEAR([Date]) ORDER BY SUM([Total Defect Qty]) DESC) rn
    FROM SupplierQuality
    GROUP BY [Defect Type], YEAR([Date])
) t
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY YearOfDefect
```

Answer (score 2):

Making the assumption I make in the comments, and this is per year, then you can use `ROW_NUMBER` to get the "top" row per group:

```sql
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT [Defect Type],
           YEAR([Date]) AS YearOfDefect,
           SUM([Total Defect Qty]) AS [Sum]
    FROM SupplierQuality
    GROUP BY [Defect Type],
             YEAR([Date]))
SELECT TOP (1) WITH TIES
       [Defect Type],
       YearOfDefect,
       [Sum]
FROM CTE
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY YearOfDefect ORDER BY [Sum] DESC);
```

Answer (score 1):

Please also refer to another method：

```
with cte
as(SELECT 
[Defect Type]
,YEAR([Date]) AS YearOfDefect
,SUM([Total Defect Qty]) AS [Sum] FROM SupplierQuality
GROUP BY [Defect Type],YEAR([Date]))
,cte2 as
(select YearOfDefect,max([Sum]) [Sum] 
from cte 
group by YearOfDefect)

select c1.[Defect Type],c2.YearOfDefect,c2.[Sum] 
from cte c1
join c2
on c1.[Defect Type]=c2.[Defect Type] and c1.YearOfDefect=c2.YearOfDefect
```